# ERROR: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "service_name" violates not-null constraint after upgrade Rails to 7.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg

Recently we had upgraded the Ruby on Rails app (Ruby 2.7.2 to 3.2 , Rails 5.2 to 7.0.6). After upgraded the versions, tested in local it was working as we expected, then we deployed the project into Heroku staging environment. When calling delayed jobs, while attachment saving getting below error

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column \"service_name\" of relation \"active_storage_blobs\" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (7713, qNKYpuwA1jQZa4i37gRu8A4N, Stagetech1_0308, application/pdf, {\"identified\":true}, 210599, dmcDLApGSoTMuSfLCm5/0w==, 2023-08-03 15:58:36.169884, null).
: INSERT INTO \"active_storage_blobs\" (\"key\", \"filename\", \"content_type\", \"metadata\", \"byte_size\", \"checksum\", \"created_at\") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING \"id\"".
```

Tried active storage installation and `rails db:migrate`. but getting the same error.

Can anyone help how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Storage uses the :service_name attribute in the active_storage_blobs table to support multiple services. This service_name attribute isn't nullable. If you haven't updated your database schema, Rails will attempt to insert null for this value and you'll get the error you're seeing.

You can try to run the following to populate db

```
rails active_storage:update
rails db:migrate
```

if not then maybe you can try to populate service_name by yourself to `local`, `amazon`, etc

```rb
class BackfillServiceNameInActiveStorageBlobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    ActiveStorage::Blob.unscoped.where(service_name: nil).in_batches.update_all(service_name: "local")
  end

  def down
    # No need to rollback
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you piowit, updated service name as default then it works..

Comment: I just upgraded from rails 5.2 to rails 6.0 and had this issue. Running the commands didn't help. But I just kept upgrading and when I got to rails 6.1 it went away.

Answer (score 0):

Do you maybe not have `config.active_storage.service` set for your staging environment?

Comment: Hi Smathy, config.active_storage.service = :amazon set for both development and production files and storage.yml also set the values as below. 
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join('storage') %>

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join('tmp/storage') %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['BUCKETEER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['BUCKETEER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  region: <%= ENV['BUCKETEER_AWS_REGION'] %>
  bucket: <%= ENV['BUCKETEER_BUCKET_NAME'] %>     it works in local but in staging it is failing.

Comment: Right, so you didn't say anything about setting that **in your staging files**, and it's your **staging** environment where you've seen this problem.

Comment: Staging settings were using production file. but it's not picking the service name from production file. After i default the service name the issue was gone..